# Get related model name from current model name in abstract model class

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django 1.11 app, I have an abstract model class `AbstractModel`, from which I subclass concrete models `FooModel` and `BarModel`. There are also concrete models `FooValue` and `BarValue` defined. From within AbstractModel, I want to define a one to one field to the corresponding `Value` model.

```
class AbstractModel(models.model)
  value = models.OneToOneField('corresponding Value class name', ...)  

  class Meta:
    abstract = True


class FooModel(AbstractModel):
  pass

class BarModel(AbstractModel):
  pass

class FooValue(models.model):
  pass

class BarValue(models.model):
  pass
```

How do I get corresponding `'XXXValue'` class name depending on which concrete `XXXModel` class is in scope?

To do this, I need the current concrete model class name `_my_class_name` in the class definition (which seems hard to impossible).